# How can i generate a documentation from a php symfony controller based on annotations

Tags: php, symfony, documentation, annotations, generator

I'm currently have a controller that serve a REST API and i'm looking for a lazy way to generate a documentation from my API controller, based on annotations.
Something like

```
@description = "this allow user to do some stuff"
@method POST
@parameters {"foo","bar"}
@return http://myserver/api-doc/views/response.xml
```

to be more clear, i don't want to generate o documentation for my php. I want to write annotations in my PHP classe to generate a documentation about what does my PHP for my clients and how they can use it with REST API calls

Comment: this looks like javadoc by using @, but javadoc isn't documented that way

Comment: the usage of "@" comes from annotations in PHP

Answer (score 1):

**[php documentation class](http://phpdocu.sourceforge.net/howto.php)** will help you.

take a look on [`apigen`](http://apigen.org/) too

Comment: I've found ApiGen but this will document the PHP methods and not the REST API made available by my PHP Controller. Tell me if i'm getting it wrong

Comment: @seetch I havn't use none of them. You must google it as per your need.